# Bot Framework Exception Handling in Channels?

Tags: botframework

I wanted to know if anyone knows what happens when a public bot on azure crashes for one user (i.e. when an Exception is thrown while a user is communicating with a bot via a channel)? Does this affect other users using the bot or the channel? Also, what happens to the conversation between the user and the bot when this crash happens, or when an exception is thrown?

Comment: With the information you have given it is just not possible to help you.  Can you please clarify your question.  What do you mean by crash?  for starters.

Comment: It is similar to what happens on any website when one user receives an err.  Other users should not be affected.  The conversation of the user who had the crash will be affected differently, depending on when the err occurred and how the bot is implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By crashes, do you mean when Errors and/or Exceptions are thrown will a user is communicating with a bot via a channel like skype, FB Messenger, etc...)? If so, the default response for an Exception/Error is "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue" -- (I see this in MS Teams when I encounter an error in my code) As shown here:

[image]

While this is vague you can always go to the [Bot Framework Portal](https://dev.botframework.com) to see more detailed error reporting. As shown here:
[image]

More than likely the users' experience will vary based on what caused the crash/error/exception.

When testing in the Emulator you may get a more detailed response, stating that an Exception occurred. You can also view the stack trace in the Emulator as well. For this reason you may want to thoroughly test your bot code there before deploying it to Azure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I mean. Will the other users be affected by that?

Comment: You're welcome! How other are affected will vary. I've seen code errors (such as infinite loops) break a bot for all users but this is usually rare. You'll most likely just experience the `Sorry my bot code is having issues` error which shouldn't cause the bot to break. Afterwards you can still communicate with the bot, assuming you don't enter the words/phrase that caused the exception again. If this helps could you mark this question as the answer?